# Pretty Tree Printing Screen limit

Tags: c, tree, screen, putty

I've been trying to print a binary tree and it's working fine when it has a few nodes. However  because the data is long integers it takes a lot of width and when there are many nodes I'm not able to print one level in one line. The nodes that don't fit are printed in a new line instead and the formatting becomes messed up. I'd like a left/right scroll bar to appear insted if that's possible. Is there any sort of command i can give?

I'm working on linux, on the command prompt via Putty.

Comment: It seems that you are printing the tree from top to bottom. (I'm assuming that because you say that you want to print one level in one line.) Couldn't printing it from left to right with simple indentation per level be an alternative? You could use the console's vertical scrollbar then.

Answer (score 2):

Try the NCURSES library.  It gives you an API for screen manipulation using a simple console.  The HOW-TO for NCURSES is at: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/index.html.